# How to sync OnetoOne relation in CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-generic-views

models:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.Char()

class BookCount(models.Model):
    book = OneToOneField(Book)
    count = SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

views:

```py
class BookCreate(CreateView):
    model = Application
```

The question is, after create Book, I want insert a record to BookCount. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `BookCount` model is required you could use a listener for the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal along the lines of this:

```
# models.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Model definitions
...

def create_book_count(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        BookCount.objects.create(book=instance)

post_save.connect(create_book_count, sender=Book)
```

If your models are really this simple, you may want to drop the `BookCount` model and add a `count` field to your `Book` model instead to reduce the complexity and overhead here. See the docs on [extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for a short overview of why it might be better to avoid the `OneToOneField` option (the wording is specific to the `User` model, but it applies here, too):

> Note that using related models results in additional queries or joins to retrieve the related data, and depending on your needs substituting the User model and adding the related fields may be your better option. However existing links to the default User model within your project’s apps may justify the extra database load.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because only init BookCount related to Book creation, futher operation on BookCount won't rely on Book.

Comment: @linbo In either case, this should create the `BookCount` objects automatically each time `Book.save` is called for a newly created `Book`.